# How can I add value to a constructor/prototype function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, prototype

Lets say I have a constructor looking like this

```
function Persons(lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
this.firstName = [];
}
```

and then a prototype like this

```
Persons.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
getName();
return firstName;
}
```

And the getName function

```
var getName = function() {
}
```

If I in getName want to send the value "Andrew" to the array this.firstName = []; how can I do that? Is it even possible?

Comment: Do they all have the same `lastName`?

Comment: Why getName() must be outside Persons context? What is the main objective of your code?

Comment: Yes, they do have the same lastName :) And yes it has to be outside of Persons context (this was just example code for a much bigger code snippet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the array to the function and fill it there:

```
Persons.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
  getName(this.firstName);
  return this.firstName;
}

var getName = function(arr) {
  arr.push("Andrew");
}
```

Or you can return the value from the function and set it in the method:

```
Persons.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
  this.firstName.push(getName());
  return this.firstName;
}

var getName = function() {
  return "Andrew";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is possible, like so:

```
var getName = function(person) {
    person.firtName.push("Andrew");
};
```

An then in your `prototype`:

```
Persons.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
    getName(this);
    return firstName;
};
```

But it doesn't look good. It seems to be a bad practice. Anyway, hope this help.

Comment: That's not a `getName` function, that's a `setName` function.

Comment: I agreed. I suppose it is a setName, it would make much more sense, but will still be a bad practice. It seems to be a functionality that allows internally call another functionality that externally provides a name. But i'm still confused with the author's objectives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `call` of a `Function`, as it follows:

```
Persons.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
    getName.call(this);
}
```

This way you bind the `this` reference to the `getName` function, thus you can safely access it as ti follows:

```
var getName = function() {
    this.firstName.push("Andrew");
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) you can find more details about `call`.